# How to move a letter in a string one position forward or backwards.?

Tags: php, string

I want something that could move a letter in a string one position backwards or forward.

Like detect a small `i` in a string like

```
ik ikdig inchf
```

and output

```
ki kidgi nichf
```

and reverse too...

And can i too add some assumptions like if there is a particular letter after the letter after `i` like if there is a `L` in the string `ikL ikgLkf iJLnm` after the word next to `i`, it should move `i` after `L`.

Actually I am trying to make a Punjabi font to Unicode Converter. In Punjabi fonts, vowels like `i` are always before the letter and in unicode, the vowvel is always after the letter. And sometimes, there are diacritics, so the vowel is after the letter and the diacritic...

Please Help.

Comment: How about showing us some of your attempts at this code?

Comment: Explode it into an array, adjust the array to your needs and glue it back together.

Comment: If you provide a sample of input string your expected output and possibly your own attempt to resolve it, you will get many more precise answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is not very clear but I think following should work:

```
$str = 'ik ikdig inchf i9';
$repl = preg_replace('/(i)(\p{L})/u', '\2\1', $str);
echo '[' . $repl . "]\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[ki kidgi nichf i9]
```

*I have used `\p{L}` and `u` modifier to make sure unicode characters are also supported.*

Answer (score -1):

you shoud find position of aim char and word
and then chang position with index in string

```
$temp=$string[$ipos];
$string[$ipos]=$string[$ipos+1];
$string[$ipos+1]=$temp;
```

if you want change position word yous should Attention word leght